# Can install specific version of Tensorflow from pipenv, but cannot install it from Pipfile

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.8, pypi, pipenv, tensorflow2.x

Really strange error where I can install `tensorflow==2.4.1` from pipenv using the command

`pipenv install tensorflow==2.4.1`

But when I put it in a pipfile in the format of:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
tensorflow = "==2.4.1"

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

and I run the command:

```
pipenv lock --clear
pipenv --rm 
pipenv install
```

I get:

```
Pipfile.lock (bf56f7) out of date, updating to (0575f6)...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed!
CRITICAL:pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.index.package_finder:Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.4.1 (from -r /var/folders/m6/kqrmfdj12x79gmbbq6f2m1ph0000gn/T/pipenvxgupglu4requirements/pipenv-puyj_a_j-constraints.txt (line 2)) (from versions: none)
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 741, in _main
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolve_packages(pre, clear, verbose, system, write, requirements_dir, packages, dev)
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 702, in resolve_packages
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, resolver = resolve(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 684, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       return resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1395, in resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, hashes, markers_lookup, resolver, skipped = actually_resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1108, in actually_resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolver.resolve()
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 833, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original command again.
 Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.4.1 (from -r /var/folders/m6/kqrmfdj12x79gmbbq6f2m1ph0000gn/T/pipenvxgupglu4requirements/pipenv-puyj_a_j-constraints.txt (line 2))
```

I have committed myself to making pipenv work and am not amenable to other solutions for package management.

Comment: I have the same problem, it happens also with tensorflow ==2.4.0 and ==2.5.0, and with both python 3.8 and 3.9, and both on macOS X 10.15 and Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this problem as it is the same for me as well. @ronin667

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this myself as I expected it to be like a requirements.txt or other languages package managers style, I found the solution here https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/

so your Pipfile will become

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
tensorflow = {version="==2.4.1"}"

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the command pipenv run:

```
pipenv run pip install tensorflow==2.4.1
```